# Send mp3 sound to different audio devices in windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, mp3, audio-streaming

I need to play mp3 sounds on different sound devices (not only the default) on Windows XP. How can I choose a sound device on windows xp to play my mp3 file? ( I am programming on C# , but C++ answer will be good as well). 
Thanks for your answers

Comment: Multiple devices simultaneously?  What API are you using for playing audio currently?

Comment: Not simultaneously, I need to give users the ability to choose the sound device. Now I am using System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer but it only plays sound on default sound device.